# Activate and deactivate a preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

I need an example-tutorial how to activate and deactivate an element in preference activity.

For example in the picture below  when the Wi-Fi check box is unselected I can not touch the Network notification check box and it turns gray, when the Wi-Fi check box is selected then I can touch the other check box.

Also how can I populate the Add Wi-Fi network tab when the whi-fi checkbox is enabled?

[image]

Answer (score 17):

We need to add in out preferences.xml file
in the preference which is depending from another preference the android:dependency="" code.

For example :

```
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="checkBox"
            android:summary="On/Off"
            android:title="Enable" />

        <ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/listOptions"
            android:entryValues="@array/listValues"
            android:key="listpref"
            android:summary="List preference example"
            android:title="List preference"
            android:dependency="checkBox" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Your preferences activity should implement `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. Be sure to register and unregister the activity with the listener.

Then in both `onResume()` and `onSharedPreferenceChanged` methods evaluate the state of the controlling preference to determine if the dependant preference should be enabled or disabled.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        final String key) {
    if (key.equals(PREFERENCE_KEY)) {
        // handle setting enabled or disabled depending on value of preference
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false)) {
            // prefField.setenabled(true);
        } else {
            // prefField.setenabled(false);
        }

    }
}
```

If you also use a PreferenceCategory then you may also look to enable or disable the category as a whole.

Comment: What is `prefField` ? how to declare that ?

Comment: prefField is whatever preference value you want to enable/disable. So for PREFERENCE_KEY I want to enable/disable PREFERENCE_KEY_CHILD so prefField is PREFERENCE_KEY_CHILD.

Answer (score 0):

When preference activity starts in onResume method check wifi connection status, or whatever you want and enable/disable appropriate preference.

It may looks similar to this, simple example, just to give you a general idea.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   boolean isConnected = getConnectionStatus();

   if(isConnected) {
     connPreference.setEnabled(false);
   } else {
     connPreference.setEnabled(true);
   }
}
```